# Setting ColorPrimary (Action Bar color) to transparent causes an exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to set my Action Bar color to transparent, so it will have the same color as the background and will also blend in with the gradient background.

I tried doing something like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

When I run my app, it launches, loads the screen for one second (all rendered correctly, action bar is transparent), then crashes to the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: background can not be translucent: #0
```

Tracing to no relevant class of my project.
If I set the parameter to a solid color, everything works fine.
Can you help me with the problem? I couldn't find any solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `MediaRouter`?

Comment: For Casting? Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app isn't crashing as a result of the `ActionBar` background being transparent, but as a result of your `colorPrimary` being transparent, in combination with using the `MediaRouter` lib.

[`MediaRouterThemeHelper.getControllerColor`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/7dbbadd44f1d8b14990cf413bace64e1535a2564/v7/mediarouter/src/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouterThemeHelper.java#L93) and [`MediaRouterThemeHelper.getButtonTextColor`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/7dbbadd44f1d8b14990cf413bace64e1535a2564/v7/mediarouter/src/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouterThemeHelper.java#L103) both make calls to [`ColorUtils.calculateContrast`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/7dbbadd44f1d8b14990cf413bace64e1535a2564/core-utils/java/android/support/v4/graphics/ColorUtils.java#L92), which is where your `IllegalArgumentException` is coming from.

`ColorUtils.calculateContrast` needs a fully opaque color in order to correctly calculate contrast, just based on the [formula being used](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef) and `MediaRouterThemeHelper` uses `colorPrimary` to determine how to theme the `MediaRouter` controller and button text color.

It looks like you're using a `NoActionBar` style, so I'm assuming you're using a `Toolbar` and just setting the `background` to be your `colorPrimary`. Instead you could just use `@android:color/transparent` directly and change your `colorPrimary` to something opaque.